# disable page scroll on touch pad scroll inside forge viewer in firefox

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a forge viewer instance taking up a small portion of my page. when the mouse pointer is on the forge's canvas and I use the touch pad 2 finger scroll, the model zooms in and out as expected but the page also scrolls up and down. how can i prevent the page from scrolling while still retaining the zooming functionality.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue unfortunately - see live demo [here](https://output.jsbin.com/wuboway/) and code [here](https://jsbin.com/wuboway/1/edit?html,js) - can you spin up a live demo for your issue as well so we can reproduce it?

Comment: I tried your demo and it does in fact work when i use a regular mouse but not while using a touch pad to scroll. I updated the question to better explain my issue.

Comment: What browser/device/trackpad is yours? Tried Chrome v70/77 on both Mac and Surface and [the page did stay put...](https://www.screencast.com/t/nkIwRhSUIvou)

Comment: Hi Bryan, the issue occurs on firefox 60/69, just so you know i am using a Dell Precision 5530 with the built in trackpad. everything works fine on chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have figured out the issue, the viewer controls bind to the DOMMouseScroll and the mousewheel on the .canvas-wrap element. this is not enough for newer versions of firefox. The controls need to also bind to the "wheel" event which seems to be the standard event for handling mouse wheel action. the following acts as a temporary fix.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("canvas-wrap")[0].addEventListener( 'wheel', NOP_VIEWER.impl.controls.mousewheel, false);
```

Comment: couldn't reproduce either on Firefox 62 ... but glad you managed to work around the issue